# How to add your own library to Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, namespaces

So i have been designig an application to run on the Zend Framework 1.11 And as any programmer would do when he sees repeated functionalities i wanted to go build a base class with said functionalities.

Now my plan is to build a library 'My' so i made a folder in the library directory in the application. So it looks like this

```
Project 
   Application 
   docs 
   library 
      My 
   public 
   test
```

So i created a  BaseController class in the My folder and then decided to have the IndexController in my application extend the BaseController.

The Basecontroller looks like this :

```
class My_BaseController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->test = 'Hallo Wereld!';
    }

}
```

And the IndexController looks like this :

```
class WMSController extends My_BaseController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        parent::indexAction();
    }

}
```

As adviced by a number of resources i tried adding the namespace for the library in the application.ini using the line

```
autoloadernamespaces.my = “My_”
```

But when i try to run this application i recieve the following error

> Fatal error: Class 'My_BaseController' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\ZendTest\application\controllers\IndexController.php

Am i missing something here? Or am i just being a muppet and should try a different approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original approach will work for you in application.ini, you just had a couple of problems with your set up.

Your application.ini should have this line:-

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "My_"
```

Also, you have to be careful with your class names, taking your base controller as an example, it should be in `library/My/Controller/Base.php` and should look like this:-

```
class My_Controller_Base extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->test = 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:-

```
class WMSController extends My_Controller_Base
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        parent::indexAction();
    }  
}
```

So, you had it almost right, but were missing just a couple of details. It is worth getting to know how autoloading works in Zend Framework and learning to use the [class naming conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.autoloading.design.html)

Comment: Just a quick note that it is almost always a bad idea to extend Zend_Controller_Action - it is generally better to create helpers or plugins. I have never found a use case for extending Zend_Controller_Action that could not be more easily tested/injected with a mixture of resources, helpers and plugins.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you 100%, but this question is about adding your own library and it seemed easier to use the OP's own example. It's probably good to have the comment here though, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the responces to my question. I am quite new to how the Zend Framework works and therefor not aquainted with the best practices commonly used.

@Shrikeh, i will have a more detailed look at helpers and plugins, thanks for the warning :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `.ini` configuration, but I add customer libraries like this (index.php):

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('My_');
```

Comment: Actually that was a typo on my part and i corrected it in the above question :)